# query result truncated after increasing max length of group concat

Tags: mysql, concatenation

i am trying to write a small query that would get data from multiple rows, concatenate them in one row, and then join them to another query.
my problem is with the group_concat.
The result is always truncated, even after setting the limit to a higher value.

This is the part of the query that contains the group concat. i tried running this part by it self, but i keep getting the same result.

Can anyone guide me if i am doing something wrong ?

Thanks,

```
SET session group_concat_max_len=10200000000;

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(  ',', relations1.nom, relations1.prenom, relations1.fonction ) SEPARATOR  ' / ' ) 
FROM relations1, demande
GROUP BY relations1.demande_id
```

Comment: Try setting globally instead: `SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len= ? `

Comment: @1000111 i am getting access denied, I just asked that i get permissions. as soon as i can test it, i will report back. thanks.

Comment: @1000111it worked thanks.